# Q: What do I do after I can read kanji, katakana, and hiragana?

Tags: speaking, japanese, writing, kanji

I'm starting to learn Japanese but I'm wondering what I do after I can read **(know katakana, hiragana, and kanji)** and *(probably)* write Japanese? How do I understand what people are saying and say it back? And how will I understand the correct spellings of words? **(and maybe learn romaji)**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Could you please improve your question by giving some more details about your learning process? As currently written, it sounds like you first want to focus on learning the writing system and that you then want to acquire oral skills. (This sounds like a bad idea, if true.) It also isn't clear whether you are looking only for a learning method or for resources.

Comment: Romaji is normally used if you want to learn Japanese before learning Kana (Katakana, Hiragana). If you know Katakana and Hiragana well, then you really don't need romaji normally. For example, books for children are always written in Kana. If any Kanji are used, pronunciation keys in kana are normally written above each chinese character, in such a book. Those pronunciation letters are sometimes called "ruby characters" but they are just small kana characters that you can read like any others.